# Choosing a networkx layout that takes edge labels into account

Tags: networkx, graphviz

I'm plotting networkx weighted graphs using the [draw_networkx_edge_labels](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels) function. My problem is that, since edges sometimes cross each other, it is not always clear from the plot which weight belongs to which edge. For instance, in the following plot it is not immediately clear whether 2 is the weight of (1,2) or (3,7).

[image: layout]]

I'm currently using the neato layout, which does not take edge labels into account. In particular, this is how I'm drawing a weighted graph `g`:

```
layout = nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(g, prog='neato')
nx.draw(g, pos=layout)
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(g, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g, pos=layout, edge_labels=edge_labels)
```

I know I can manually control the position of the label along an edge using the `label_pos` parameter, but my question is whether there exists a way to automatically plot the graph such that edge labels do not usually collide (either using a layout that takes labels into account or a method that "neatly" selects label positions along edges).

I'm not expecting something that always works, but since my graphs are relatively sparsely connected, I hope there's a method that at least has a tendency to work well.

Answer (score 0):

I have been meaning to implement this in [netgraph](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph), my fork of the networkx drawing utilities, for a while now. Unfortunately, I have a job interview on Thursday, so I won't have time to write this anytime soon. The basic idea, however, is pretty simple, and is also already implemented in some R packages such as `ggrepel` and also [`ggnetwork`](https://briatte.github.io/ggnetwork/).

The basic idea is that you use a force directed layout to position your labels, given a predetermined and fixed layout for your nodes and edges. So:

1. Compute a node layout using the layout of your choice.
2. Partition each edge into a chain of many, many nodes, and compute the positions of the "edge nodes" using the already known positions of the source and target nodes of the edge. This partitioning is to give each edge a "mass" in the following force directed layout.
3. For each edge, add a "label" node and connect it to the most central "edge node".
4. Compute a force-directed layout keeping all nodes but the label nodes fixed (e.g. using `spring_layout` in networkx).

You should now have sensible edge label coordinates that do not overlap any of the edges. Use `plt.annotate` to plot a connection between the edge and the edge label.